# Jquery fade in letters on different lines

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade in letters one a at a time I have this working but I'm trying to do this on different lines here's my code:

```
var string = "First Line Second Line" 
stringCount = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('#html1').append(string[stringCount]);
    stringCount += 1;
},100);
```

I've tried `/n` and `%0D%0A` in the string but it dosent work. Is it possible to do this without outputing this `/n` and `%0D%0A`  in the string.

Comment: Have you tried `<br />`? (And by the way, it's `\n`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var string = "First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line" 
stringCount = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('#html1').append(string[stringCount] == "\n" ? "<br>" : string[stringCount]);
    stringCount += 1;
},100);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m37Dd/)

Comment: works thanks but I dont really understand it. what's is the question mark for

Comment: `? :` structure is shorcut for `if/else`